# Make linux boot with a static IP at kernel compilation

Tags: linux, static, ip, kernel, config

Here is my problem: I have a arago Linux distribution (custom from Texas Instrument) that is running on an ARM processor. I want to do TFTP between my HOST (running on linux too, Ubuntu) and my board. Sadly the network I am on (school) doesn't allow my ARAGO to get IP from the DHCP server. And I can't directly write a static IP in /etc/network/interfaces because no memory space left on my board.

The only solution I see his to configure before compilation of the kernel a static IP that will be on my interface.

I've gone through the .config file and also more friendly menuconfig interface, but I didn't saw anything about configuring the future IP of the embedded linux. Do you know if it's possible ? It should...

Thank you very much

Comment: The network stack configuration isn't part of the kernel config, so it has no knowledge of this.  The kernel doesn't know what devices might be added at the OS level.

Comment: Logic. So am I scewed  ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Do you have access to shell in your board and use ifconfig command to Assign a IP Address?

Comment: Yes I have acces but My FileSytem is in a short memory space (512MB) and I can only write in memory in /tmp, all the other repertories are full no inode left...

Comment: I will try to install a dhcp server on my host, it should work.